# Cursor query for name with diacritical sign

Tags: android

In my android app i want to search for contact start with specific char.
So far i had selection looks like this

```
mSelectionClause = NAME + " LIKE \"" + name + "%\"";
```

that select all contact start with specific char and it work fine till i start look for contact start with ł, then i can select only contact start with small ł and all dontact start with Ł are not displayed.

I try add `COLLATE LOCALIZED` as i did it before to sort, so now my selection is

```
mSelectionClause = NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED LIKE \"" + name + "%\"";
```

but i still can take only result with letter i wrote, small or big.

in ex. i have records like

> łukasz
>
> Łuki
>
> ałuki

when i search for record start with "ł" i get only

> łukasz

but i want to get both łukasz and Łuki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert both your values to the same case

```
mSelectionClause = "lower(" + NAME + ") LIKE \"" + name.toLowerCase() + "%\"";
```

Or...

```
mSelectionClause = NAME + " LIKE \"" + name + "%\" COLLATE NOCASE";
```

Comment: `mSelectionClause = "lower(" + NAME + ") LIKE \"" + name.toLowerCase() + "%\"";` works after mod, now its looks like `mSelectionClause = "lower(" + NAME + ") LIKE \"" + name.toLowerCase() + "%\""
     + " OR "
     + "upper(" + NAME + ") LIKE \"" + name.toUpperCase() + "%\"";`

Comment: there should be no difference, you are comparing łukasz=łukasz or ŁUKASZ=ŁUKASZ

Comment: yea it should not be any difference but when i use only lower case then when i search for "Ł" i recieve only łukasz

Comment: So post a full code here, how do you retrieve records? Because maybe you also query for lower case.